# angularjs dynamic label name for array inside array push

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am creating array using below format,

```
angular.forEach(value.data, function(value1, key1) {
    shiftArrayList.push({
        shift: value1.shiftName
    });
    dataArrayList.push({
        safeDayCount: value1.safeDayCount,
        accidentCount: value1.accidentCount,
        hazardCount: value1.hazardCount,
        nearMissCount: value1.nearMissCount
    });
});
```

and the result for dataArrayList will be like,

```
"safeDayCount": 0,
"accidentCount": 0,
"hazardCount": 39,
"nearMissCount": 0
```

and it continues. But i need to append the label name inside the foreach and for every label i need to append `value1.shiftName`. like `safeDayCount + "_"+value1.shiftName`. So it will be like `safeDayCount_X, accidentCount_X, hazardCount_X, nearMissCount_X.`. Please help me to append the value.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepare the object like this

```
var props = [ "safeDayCount", "accidentCount", "hazardCount", "nearMissCount" ];
var obj = {};
props.forEach( function(item){
  obj[ item + "_" + value1.shiftName ] = value1[ item ];  
});

dataArrayList.push( obj );
```

Comment: it is not working it is showing _Unexpected token +_